# Check immediately if bullet would collide with wall

Tags: phaser-framework

[image]

Currently I check on `update()` if the bullet collides with the collision wall like so:

```
game.physics.arcade.collide(weapon.bullets, collisionLayer, collisionHandler, processCallback, this);
```

This works! But when I set the `weapon.bulletSpeed = 2000;` really high (above 900) this doesn't work any more, and the bullets "tunnel" through the collision walls.

I am trying to implement a sniper like rifle, where little to no time passes for the bullet to hit the obstacle. So I would like to know how to calculate the collision coordinates of the bullet with the collision wall the moment the player shoots. How can I do this?

Answer (score 1):

The bullet may be traveling in steps to large as to not actually intersect.

Consider making a line of the form y = mx + b to represent the path of the bullet, then the two vertical lines that represent the wall.

Solve algebratically for the intersection of the bullet line, and each of the two wall lines.   If there is a solution, then the bullet does hit the wall.

Comment: Thanks for the answer. But my question is more phaser framework specific. I would like to know, if there is a build in method for this task.

Answer (score 0):

I found a build in solution in phaser. This demo shows how it works:

http://phaser.io/examples/v2/tilemaps/tilemap-ray-cast